# Spring MVC JSP is not rendering

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat

I am currently learning Spring MVC. I am trying to call a controller which will return the JSP. But when I am hitting the request it is printing the JSP code in browser and not rendering it.

File `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringWeb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>SpringWeb Maven Webapp</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.19</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>SpringWeb</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>          
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>SpringWeb</path>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

File `HomeController.java`

```
package controller;

import configuration.HomeConfig;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import repository.SpitterRepository;

@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/spitter","/home"})
public class HomeController {

    private SpitterRepository spitterRepository;

    public HomeController()
    {

    }
    @Autowired
    public HomeController(SpitterRepository spitterRepository)
    {
        this.spitterRepository = spitterRepository;
        System.out.println("HomeController Constructor");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home()
    {
        System.out.println("Calling home html");
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/spittles")
    public String spittles(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute(spitterRepository.findSpittles(Long.MAX_VALUE,20));
        return "spittles";
    }
}
```

HomeConfig.java

```
package configuration;

import controller.HomeController;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"controller","repository"})
public class HomeConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver createViewResolver()
    {
        System.out.println("This is View Resolver");
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        //internalResourceViewResolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        internalResourceViewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }

    /*@Bean
    public HomeController createHomeController()
    {

        return new HomeController();
    }*/


    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

HomeAppInitializer.java

```
package configuration;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class HomeAppInitalizer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        System.out.println("This is Servlet Config Classes");
        return new Class[]{HomeConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/*"};
    }
}
```

spitters.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>First JSP</title>
</head>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
<body>
<h3>SPITTLES</h3><br>
<strong>Current Time is</strong>: <%=new Date() %>

</body>
</html>
```

So when I run the project using the command tomcat7:run and calling the following url http://localhost:8080/SpringWeb/home/spittles, the enitre JSP code is printing in browser and rendering does not happen, I am stuck in this for 2 days. Kindly help me in resolving the issue. I am using Intellij IDE.

Comment: Do you have any desire to not use Spring Boot? The reason I ask is because it takes care of a lot of the configuration issues and its pretty easy to configure it so that you dont have to just use JSP, you can use other  view types like html for Thymeleaf. Even if you intend to use JSP using Spring Boot you won't have to setup as much of that annoying config boiler plate. https://start.spring.io/

Answer (score 0):

You code wrong syntax at

```java
@Autowired
public HomeController(SpitterRepository spitterRepository)
{
    this.spitterRepository = spitterRepository;
    System.out.println("HomeController Constructor");
}
```

You have wrong web configuration. Fix like this

```java
package com.example;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        final InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        bean.setOrder(2);
        return bean;
    }

    /** Static resource locations including themes*/
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/", "/resources/")
            .setCachePeriod(3600)
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }
    // Other configuration not display at here.
}
```

You maybe put JSP files in wrong folder.

You tried http://localhost:8080/SpringWeb/home/spittles

I assumpt you use folder `/WEB-INF/view` , then file `spittles.jsp` should has path `/WEB-INF/view/home/spittles.jsp`

See sample at

- https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-web-modules/spring-mvc-basics/src/main/java/com/baeldung/spring/web/config/WebConfig.java#L44-L51
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-view-resolver-tutorial